# Inner product in C

Tags: c

I wrote this code for a homework question that wants me to write inner product by using pointer arithmetic -NOT SUBSCRIPTING- to visit array elements. But, program doesn't allow me to enter number after enter third element. Why?

```
int inner_product(int *a, int *b, int size) 
{
  int sum = 0, i;

  for (i=0; i<size; i++) 
  {
    printf("enter value for first array: ");
    scanf("%d",*(a+i));
  }

  for (i=0; i<size; i++) 
  {
    printf("enter value for second array: ");
    scanf("%d",*(b+i));
  }

  for (i=0; i<size; i++) 
  sum += *(a+i) * *(b+i);

   return sum; 
}


int main()
{
    int n, *a, *b;
    printf("How many elements do you want to store?  ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    a=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    b=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    printf("%d\n",inner_product(a,b,n));

    free(a);
    free(b);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",*(a+i));` --> `scanf("%d", a+i);`. ditto.

Comment: and do not cast `malloc`'s return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the warnings.

```
$ gcc main.c 
main.c: In function ‘inner_product’:
main.c:11:15: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%d",*(a+i));
               ^
main.c:17:15: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%d",*(b+i));
```

If I fix the warnings, then I can enter 4 elements:

```
$ ./a.out 
How many elements do you want to store?  4
enter value for first array: 2
enter value for first array: 3
enter value for first array: 4
enter value for first array: 5
enter value for second array: 3
enter value for second array: 4
enter value for second array: 5
enter value for second array: 6
68
```

I just changed the call from int to pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int inner_product(int *a, int *b, int size)
{
    int sum = 0, i;

    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("enter value for first array: ");
        scanf("%d",(a+i));
    }

    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("enter value for second array: ");
        scanf("%d",(b+i));
    }

    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        sum += *(a+i) * *(b+i);

    return sum;
}


int main() {
    int n, *a, *b;
    printf("How many elements do you want to store?  ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    b = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    printf("%d\n", inner_product(a, b, n));

    free(a);
    free(b);
}
```

Comment: Your inner_product method should just compute the inner product, nothing more - it shouldn't ask for the data to be input - that should be done either in main() or in a separate method before calling inner_product().

Comment: @FredK It was OP's indention to do that. You should comment that on the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `*(a+i)` and `*(b+i)` in the calls to `scanf` is not right. They need to be `(a+i)` and `(b+i)`.

You are running into undefined behavior since you are passing the wrong argument to `scanf`.

You need to up the compiler warning level to detect these errors at compile time.

I get the following warnings when I use `gcc -Wall`:

```
soc.c: In function ‘inner_product’:
soc.c:11:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d",*(a+i));
     ^
soc.c:11:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
soc.c:17:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d",*(b+i));
     ^
soc.c:17:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
```